# Yii call CButtonColumn from other widget

Tags: yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

i have created new widget to display information in admin view. Final view must be same as CGridView, but with different logic for columns. Everything works fine, except when i try to call CButtonColumn column.

```
foreach ($this->columns as $column) {
     if (is_array($column) && isset($column['class']) {
         $this->renderColumnWidget($column);
     }
}

/* ... */

protected function renderColumnWidget($column)
{
    $widgetClass = $column->class;
    unset($column->class);
    if (strpos($widgetClass, '.') === false) {
        $widgetClass = 'zii.widgets.grid.'.$widgetClass;
    }

    $this->widget($widgetClass, $column); // Error from here
}
```

So basically here i check if there is class attribute in column and call that widget. But i get error: `CButtonColumn and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "run".`

What am i doing wrong? CButtonColumn don't have `run` method, and i don't want to extend this class.

Answer (score 0):

You this as a function like this to initiate your columns

```
    protected function initColumns(){
        foreach($this->columns as $i=>$column) {
            if(is_string($column))
                $column=$this->createDataColumn($column);
            else {
                if(!isset($column['class']))
                    $column['class']='CDataColumn';
                $column=Yii::createComponent($column, $this);
            }
            if($column->id===null)
                $column->id=$id.'_c'.$i;
            $this->columns[$i]=$column;
        }
        foreach($this->columns as $column)
            $column->init();
    }
```